# Typescript (ts2322) function returning interface

Tags: typescript

```
export interface AWSTags {
  CreatedBy: string;
  Environment: EnvironmentMap;
  Name: string;
  OwnedBy: string;
  Platform: string;
  Product: string;
  Runbook: string;
  Service: string;
}
```

Some other file has this method to return an object that matches the interface.

```
export const getAWSTags = (stackName: string, environment: EnvironmentMap, createdBy: string): AWSTags => ({
  CreatedBy: createdBy,
  Environment: environment,
  Name: stackName,
  OwnedBy: "owner",
  Platform: "platform",
  Product: "product",
  Runbook: "url",
  Service: `${stackName}-service`,
});
```

For context, **EnvironmentMap** is a type that returns one of three strings.

When I try to assign the return value to AWS tags, which expects the following type, it returns 2322.

```
readonly tags?: {
  [key: string]: string;
};
```

```
const app = new App();
const stack = new Stack(app, stackName, {
  env: {
    account: AWS.ACCOUNT,
    region: AWS.REGION,
  },
  tags: getAWSTags(stackName, environment, 'creator'),
});
```

```
Type 'AWSTags' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'AWSTags'.ts(2322)
```

What are different approaches to solve this problem or alternatives?

**EDIT**: This seems to remove the error but not sure how valid is.

```
export interface AWSTags {
  [key: string]: string;
  CreatedBy: string;
  Environment: EnvironmentMap;
  Name: string;
  OwnedBy: string;
  Platform: string;
  Product: string;
  Runbook: string;
  Service: string;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a hard time to follow your problem. Please, could you rephrase it and provide examples of what exactly you do that make it work/not work?

Comment: I've added the function call, it basically complains (and it makes sense) that the return type from the method is AWSTags and not the one that it wants even though the object is keys that are strings and string values. @carlosV2

Comment: Please provide the full error.

Comment: Like @Lioness100 said, provide the error message. Also, do you know what is the expected type? If so, please, provide it too.

Comment: Error added to the post, expected is to match the one for the tags { [key: string]: string }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, despite the final JS is the same, conceptually, you are passing an object instance into something that is expecting a PoJo.

Basically, this:

```
export interface AWSTags {
  CreatedBy: string;
  Environment: EnvironmentMap;
  Name: string;
  OwnedBy: string;
  Platform: string;
  Product: string;
  Runbook: string;
  Service: string;
}
```

Is declaring in TS that you have an instance that matches this declaration but this does not mean that your object will *only* be composed with those values.

In order to fix this, you need to change from using an interface to just having a mere type:

```
export type AWSTags = {
  CreatedBy: string;
  Environment: EnvironmentMap;
  Name: string;
  OwnedBy: string;
  Platform: string;
  Product: string;
  Runbook: string;
  Service: string;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the interface, you can deconstruct the resulting object before injecting it into `tags`:

```
const stack = new Stack(app, stackName, {
  // ...
  tags: {...getAWSTags(stackName, environment, 'creator')},
});
```

Comment: Cool, I'm glad it worked! Please, if you are happy with, would you mind to accept the answer? :-)